# mongoid update_attributes changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, activerecord, mongoid

I want to update_attributes and than check if information is changed

You can simply pass this code to `rails console` in existing rails + mongoid project

```
class TestModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :name, type: String
end

test = TestModel.new({:name => "name 1"})
test.save()
=> true

test
=> created_at: 2012-11-14 13:48:26 UTC, updated_at: 2012-11-14 13:48:26 UTC

test.changed?
=> false
test.name_changed?
=> false

test.update_attributes({:name => "name 2"})
=> true

test.changed?
=> false
test.name_changed?
=> false

test
=> created_at: 2012-11-14 13:48:26 UTC, updated_at: 2012-11-14 13:49:23 UTC
```

Am I doing something wrong or this is a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its perfectly logic.

Dirty methods are meant to be used to check if an object has changed **before** it's saved. By definition a persisted object has no pending changes.

You should do:

```
test.assign_attributes(attributes)
test.changed? #=> true
test.save
```

[See method definition](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Persistence#update_attributes-instance_method).

Comment: I was trying to do it ActiveRecord style, using the changed and changes attributes and they were producing empty hashes and arrays respectively. Then I used assign_attributes and then only after that, it reported the changes. So for Mongoid, that part is required.